# What is the breakdown for Java's lambda syntax?

Tags: java, syntax, lambda, java-8

Please explain the syntax for Java 8's lambda methods.

There are a lot of explanations out there for *what* lambda functions are, but I can't find a thorough explanation of the syntax, and I am finding it very difficult to learn to replicate the syntax correctly because I don't understand *why* they're written as they are.

Here's a common case that I run into, courtesy NetBeans:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        new MainAppJFrame();
    });
}
```

So somehow, the following lambda expression is resolving into an anonymous `Runnable` object's run() method:

```
() -> {
    // do stuff
}
```

The `->` is the lambda syntax proper, right? And the curly braces are simply containing the anonymous method code. Are the parentheses an empty argument, because in this case we're creating a `Runnable.run()` method?

This is all rather unclear to me. I assume the compiler knows to instantiate an anonymous `Runnable` based on the type expected by the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` method? What would happen if there were two `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` methods which differ only in parameter list? Obviously there aren't in this specific case, but it's possible elsewhere:

```
interface ExampleLambdaConsumer {
    public void doSomething(Runnable r);
    public void doSomething(java.lang.reflect.Method m);
}

class C implements ExampleLambdaConsumer {
    // implementations for doSomething methods here

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doSomething(() -> {
            // lambda method body here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax (and also the section on Target Typing) though it doesn't address the "why" part of the question.

Comment: See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27 the lambda expression section in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: BTW Your code is the same as `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(MainAppJFrame::new);`

Comment: @David Very helpful link, thank you. I _always_ forget about the JLS, had I checked there I would have either asked a better question or not had to ask at all.

Comment: @Peter Ah, thanks for that. I hadn't encountered method reference expressions before, I'm having a read of [JLS § 15.13, Method Reference Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) right now.

Comment: @muffin In reality, all lambdas are turned into a method reference. It will create a synthetic method as required and turn it into a method reference.  The method generated will have a name name like `lambda$$xxx$$2`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Syntax is:

```
arguments -> body
```

where `arguments` can be either

- `()`
- a single variable if the type of that variable can be inferred from the context
- a sequence of variables, with or without types (or since Java 11, with `var`), in parentheses.
  Examples: `(x)`, `(x, y)`, `(int x, int y)`, `(var x, var y)` (Java 11+).
  The following are invalid: `(int x, y)`, `(x, var y)`, `(var x, int y)`

and `body` can be either an expression or a `{...}` block with statements. The expression (other than a method or constructor call) is simply returned, i.e. `() -> 2` is equivalent to `() -> {return 2;}`

---

In case of lambda expressions like `() -> f()` (the body is a method or constructor call expression):

- if `f()` returns `void`, they are equivalent to `() -> { f(); }`
- otherwise, they are equivalent to either `() -> { f(); }` or `() -> { return f(); })`. The compiler infers it from the calling context, but usually it will prefer the latter.

Therefore, if you have two methods: `void handle(Supplier<T>)` and `void handle(Runnable)`, then:

- `handle(() -> { return f(); })` and `handle(() -> x)` will call the first one,
- `handle(() -> { f(); }` will call the second one, and
- `handle(() -> f())`:

  - if `f()` returns `void` or a type that is not convertible to `T`, then it will call the second one
  - if `f()` returns a type that is convertible to `T`, then it will call the first one

---

The compiler tries to match the type of the lambda to the context. I don't know the exact rules, but the answer to:

> What would happen if there were two SwingUtilities.invokeLater methods which differ only in parameter list?

is: it depends on what would be those parameter lists. If the other `invokeLater` had also exactly one parameter and that parameter would be of type that is also an interface with one method of type `void*()`, well, then it would complain that it cannot figure out which method you mean.

Why are they written as they are? Well, I think it's because syntax in C# and Scala is almost the same (they use `=>` rather than `->`).

Comment: Thanks! Accepted because your short, to-the-point answer really helped me to get my head around Java lambdas.

Comment: arguments -> body :-) Why isn't the Oracle tutorial as simple as this?

Comment: This is by far the best answer I have seen on this subject.

Answer (score 12):

The syntax is

```
(parameter_list_here) -> { stuff_to_do; }
```

The curly braces can be omitted if it's a single expression. The regular parentheses around the parameter list can be omitted if it's a single parameter.

The syntax only works for all functional interfaces. The @FunctionalInterface annotation tells the compiler that you intend to write such an interface and gives a compile error if you do not meet the requirement(s) - for example it must only have 1 overrideable method.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface TestInterface {
    void dostuff();
}
```

Runnable is also declared like that. Other interfaces are not, and they cannot be used with lambda functions.

Now that we've made a new functional interface with a method that takes no parameters, how about we test the question you had about "collision" in the signatures?

```
public class Main {
    private void test(Runnable r) {

    }
    private void test(TestInterface ti) {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        test(() -> { System.out.println("test");})
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface TestInterface {
        void dostuff();
    }
}
```

Result: compile error: ambigouous call to method test.

You see, the compiler/VM(if done runtime) finds the appropriate methods and their parameter list and sees if the parameter is a functional interface and if it is it creates an anonymous implementation of that interface. Technically (in byte code) it's different from an anonymous class, but otherwise identical (you won't see Main$1.class files).

Your example code (courtesy of Netbeans) can also be replaced with

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(MainAppJFrame::new);
```

Btw. :)

Comment: It is possible to use a lambda where a reference to any interface with a single abstract method is expected. The interface need not have the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation. That annotation is a signal of *intent* to be used with lambda, and it changes the javadoc, but it's not required.

Comment: The curly braces can **not** be omitted for a single statement, only for an expression. It works for method invocations because a method invocation is both, a statement *and* an expression. E.g. `()->throw x;` does not work. On the other hand, the parentheses around the parameters may be omitted for a single parameter.

Comment: Thank you both. I'm unsure if I should edit my post since you're both correct, or leave it as comments.

Comment: @Xabster: if you have the time, improve your answer. That’s what the edit facility is for.

Comment: +1 for the discussion of @FunctionalInterface and for your take on my example. Thanks! Also, I am echoing Holger's encouragement to incorporate the suggested corrections for posterity.

Answer (score 11):

Lambda Expressions are basically adopted in Java 8 to **simplify overriding process function as anonymous functions**.

They are mere shortcut to **Override** old java anonymous functions.

Refer following example:

Suppose you have **interface A** which has only one method declared like below:

```
interface A{        
    void print();           
}
```

now with **old java** style we'll **override** this in anonymous way like below:

```
new A() {           
        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("in a print method");                
        }           
};
```

additionally now with java 8 lambda expression we'll use it like below:

```
() -> System.out.println("in a print method");
```

Here we can pass parameters required to method   before `->` operator
and  then  overridden body after  `->` operator.

the only more settings that we need to achieve this is that we need to declare interface with **@FunctionalInterface**  as below:

```
 @FunctionalInterface
 interface A{        
    void print();           
 }
```

**Note:** - A lambda expression can only be used for a "functional" interface that has only one non-default method.

Comment: easy to comprehend explanation

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is confusing.
It drives me around the twist.
If it was not for Intellij, correcting me I would get it wrong.

Compiles OK.

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Predicate<Integer> even = integer -> {return (integer%2 == 0);};
    }
}
```

Compiles OK.

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Predicate<Integer> even = integer -> {return integer%2 == 0;};
    }
}
```

Does NOT Compile, since it is not a statement anymore.

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Predicate<Integer> even = integer -> {return integer%2 == 0};
    }
}
```

Does NOT Compile, since it is not a statement anymore and the return statement has been removed.

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Predicate<Integer> even = integer -> {integer%2 == 0};
    }
}
```

Compiles OK.

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Predicate<Integer> even = integer -> integer%2 == 0;
    }
}
```

So moral of the story is, if you use the brackets what is inside must
be a statement, and it must return the type expected by the Functional interface single abstract method (i.e. the only one that is not a default).

I actually wrote it more for myself than anything else, cause it was bugging me.