# Confused with Java8 lambda and auto generated constructor?

Tags: java-8, lombok

```
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   class Foo {
        @NonNull private final UnaryOperator<String> myStr;
        @NonNull private final Runnable start, stop;

        public foo (UnaryOperator<String> myStr) {
            this(myStr, () -> {}, () -> {};
        }
    ..
    }
```

What does this line do:

```
> this(myStr, () -> {}, () -> {});
> () -> {}
```

No other constructors in this class.
I don't understand how to read it even.

Comment: Lambda functions?

Comment: There has to be another constructor with a `foo(UnaryOperator<String> myStr, Runnable r1, Runnable r2) {...}` signature.

Comment: _What does this line do?_ It fails to compile.

Comment: Btw classes are named in `UpperCamelCase`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the breakdown for Java's lambda syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192108/what-is-the-breakdown-for-javas-lambda-syntax)

Comment: Thanks @Flown .. appreciate that.. that's what I missed .. Updated question. .. but anyway if you copy paste that as answer I could accept it! apologize for this, I'm brand new in Java .. coming from Python/C++ background. Please re-consider your down votes! *frown face*

Comment: “I don't understand how to read it even”—There are multiple errors within that code, so well, I also don’t understand how to read that…

Comment: Where do those annotations come from? Lombok? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, Lombok .. I just took snippet from somewhere .. hence wasn't able to make Complete example.

Comment: Well, posting incomplete snippets is just like someone would end the the middle of

Comment: Lombok is magic. If you're asking about the syntax, the previous link explains what a lambda expression is.

Comment: Thanks @Holger nice way to roast beginner!

Comment: @code muncher: “beginner”? You are a member for more than 4 years now. You should know how relevant complete code examples are. So why do you post a code fragment with inconsistent names (class name `Foo`, constructor `foo`) and missing braces? This isn’t even related to lambda expressions, your question is about. If you just copy the actual code, you have issues with, such things can’t happen.

Comment: "Beginner" = Reading Java and now I now Lombok too. so I'll be careful next time to not to miss those annotations. Also Re-read it I asked this too: - > () -> {}  .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`@RequiredArgsConstructor`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Constructor.html) annotation from Lombok creates the constructor for you.

As a beginner you should avoid Lombok, because there is too much codegeneration involved.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Foo {
    @NonNull private final UnaryOperator<String> myStr;
    @NonNull private final Runnable start, stop;

    public foo (UnaryOperator<String> myStr) {
        this(myStr, () -> {}, () -> {};
    }
    //...
}
```

Is going to be:

```
class Foo {
    private final UnaryOperator<String> myStr;
    private final Runnable start, stop;

    public foo (UnaryOperator<String> myStr) {
        this(myStr, () -> {}, () -> {};
    }

    public foo (UnaryOperator<String> myStr, Runnable start, Runnable stop) {
        //Lombok generated checks from @NonNull
        if(myStr == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        if(start == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        if(stop == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        this.myStr = myStr;
        this.start = start;
        this.stop = stop;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Flown .. And () -> {} actually just empty method. , that's another thing that was confusing .. I'm working on project so I have to use/understand Lombok. But thanks for this!

Comment: @codemuncher Yes `() -> {}` is equivalent to `new Runnable() { public void run() {}}`