# What's is the functionality of ()-> in collection.add(()->7);

Tags: java, lambda

I know this would the lame question on Stackoverflow today...but still I would like to find the functionality for the below snippet in java

ideally, we should be passing a 'Scoreable scoreable' object to collection.add but what is this ()->5 ?? and how its coverting the int value to Scoreable type

```
public class ScoreCollectionTest {

    public void addTwoNumbersForMean() {

        ScoreCollection collection = new ScoreCollection();

        collection.add(()->5);
        collection.add(()->7);

    }

}
```

```
public class ScoreCollection {

    private List<Scoreable> scores = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Scoreable scoreable) {
        scores.add(scoreable);
    }

    public int arithmeticMean() {
        int total = scores.stream().mapToInt(Scoreable::getScore).sum();
        return total / scores.size();
    }
}
```

Here is `Scoreable` Interface

```
public interface Scoreable { 
    int getScore(); 
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the definition of `Scoreable`, it might be obvious.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192108/what-is-the-breakdown-for-javas-lambda-syntax

Comment: @Smutje, 
```
public interface Scoreable {

 int getScore();
}
```

()-> represents the return of int value from Scorable interface, as it has only one method ?

Comment: It might be more understandable if you know about lambdas, and read it as `() -> 5` (with whitespace that is). Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192108/what-is-the-breakdown-for-javas-lambda-syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`collection.add(()->5);` is a syntactic sugar for:

```
collection.add(new Scoreable() {

  @Override
  int getScore() {
    return 5;
  }
});
```

Since Scoreable has only one method, it qualifies as a `@FunctionalInterface` and can be used in lambda expressions instead of anonymous classes

Comment: Pedantry: it doesn't qualify as a `@FunctionalInterface`. That would imply it physically has the annotation -- the annotation being effectively just some meta-data -- "*the compiler will treat any interface meeting the definition of a functional interface as a functional interface regardless of whether or not a FunctionalInterface annotation is present*". The correct statement would be "it qualifies as a functional interface".

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call it syntactic sugar. Indeed the effect is the same, but the semantics of a lambda expression are a little different. For instance, lambda expressions work with enclosing scope.

Comment: The answer is a bit incorrect. The lambda does not get compiled into an anonymous class. Logically it achieves the same result, but the mechanism is different. https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-8-enhancements/java-lambda-functional-aspect.html

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what Scoreable is, I'm assuming it is an interface with one method (the method's name is irrelevant) that takes no arguments and returns an integer.

The compiler interprets it as a functional interface (because it fulfills all requirements of a functional interface) and `()->5` is a lambda expression of a parameterless method that always returns 5.

Comment: ```
public interface Scoreable {

 int getScore();
}
```