# Collectors toMap() - value mapper from Map.Entry to Map structure

Tags: java, java-11, collectors

I recently stumbled across the following issue.

Basically I have a set of  pairs which i want to transform to a map of maps . Below is the code snippet:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String,String> > testSet = new HashSet<>(
            Arrays.asList(
                    entry("key1","value1"),
                    entry("key1","value1")
                    )
    );

    Map<String,Map<String,String>> testMap = testSet
            .stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            entry -> entry.getKey(),
                            entry-> {
                                Map.ofEntries(
                                        entry(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue() + "2")
                                );
                            }
                    )
            );
```

The above snippet does not compile because the functions that are passed to the *toMap* expect Objects and not Map.Entry objects, so the compiler cannot find the methods specific to the Map.Entry.

I  have no idea why this happens so any help is appreciated.

Comment: remove the braces `{}` in value mapping

Comment: Possible duplicate [What is the breakdown for Java's lambda syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192108/what-is-the-breakdown-for-javas-lambda-syntax/25197679)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> testMap = testSet
        .stream()
        .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        entry -> entry.getKey(),
                        entry -> Map.ofEntries(entry(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue() + "2"))
                )
        );
```

When you are using a lambda expression body with curly braces, it must contain a return statement (assuming the corresponding functional interface's method has a return value).

If the lambda expression's body is just a single expression, it doesn't have to be wrapped in braces.

Comment: But as a side note, `Map.ofEntries(Map.entry(a, b))` is a verbose version of `Map.of(a, b)`.